# UL rebelling. Can't have elements next to each other

Tags: html, css

First of all Hello!

I've been working on a basic project and I run into a problem.
I have my menu bar which I want on the left of the page. Then I want an textblock in the middle. on the right I want an login option, advertisement space and a little google maps image.

I'll show you the code, with the text in the text block taken out.

```
<div>
    <img src="banner1.jpg" class="banner">
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="menuopmaak" id="contentmiddle">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="tekstblok" id="contentmiddle">
    <h1>Wij zijn altijd de goedkoopste</h1>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor.</p>
```

```
<div class="Loginblok" id="contentmiddle">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input required type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <label for="password">wachtwoord</label>
            <input required type="text" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="wachtwoord"/>
    </fieldset>
</div></b>
```

My CSS

```
ul li  {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menuopmaak {
  width: 100%;
  color: #CCC;

}

.tekstblok {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  clear:both;
}

#contentmiddle {
  float:left;
}
```

What to do ? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The UL is spanning over the whole page. I would like to have the menu (Unordered list with links in it ) to be on the left of the screen. The text block next to it and the login thingy on the far right

Comment: A given `id` may only occur once in an `html` document. You have `id="contentmiddle"` in three `<div>`s. It is okay to make `contentmiddle` a `class` instead of an `id`: `<div class="menuopmaak contentmiddle">`, `<div class="tekstblok contentmiddle">`, `<div class="Loginblok contentmiddle">`

Comment: You have a stray `</b>` at the end of `.Loginblok`, which doesn't need to be there. Also you are missing the closing `</div>` at the end of `.tekstblok`.

Comment: Changed it. Thank you @Rounin

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put you're menu to the left you should put you're float on the menu.
You should have:

```
.menuopmaak {
   float:left;
}
```

and not

```
#contentmiddle {
  float:left;
}
```

Then delete the clear and it would be ok.

Hope it's what you wanted ;)

Comment: I changed it. Now sadly the login bar is on the far bottom. Not even next to the textblock anymore. I am looking for a way to have them all next to each other.

Comment: Because you add you're clear to early. Delete the clear then they would be next.

Comment: amazing. Thank you @Ponsaille !

Comment: As someone else says (I didn't chek that) but you invert class and id. The ID should be unique and the class can be use on multiple div.
Have a good day

Comment: Also changed that! sometimes the little facts like that slip away. Just started coding. Really appreciate your help @Ponsaille

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is something approaching what you are looking for:

```css
.banner {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 728px;
height: 90px;
margin: 12px auto;
border: 1px solid rgba(63,63,63,1);
}

.content {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1072px;
}

.content div {
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12px;
}

ul li  {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.menuopmaak {
  color: #CCC;
  width: 200px;
}

.tekstblok {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.Loginblok {
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class="banner" src="banner1.jpg" >
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="menuopmaak">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="tekstblok">
    <h1>Wij zijn altijd de goedkoopste</h1>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>

<div class="Loginblok">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input required type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="e-mail"/>
        <label for="password">wachtwoord</label>
            <input required type="text" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="wachtwoord"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Please do compare and contrast with your own markup above and ask questions in the comments below, so you can clarify what changes I've made to your markup and why elements display differently in the modified example above.

Comment: It is indeed the way I would like it to be! I'll look through the code and see if there are things which I don't understand. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, to begin with, It doesn't display over the whole screen anymore but in the middle. I am curious as to how that happened? I see a lot of "position: relative;" Is that why ?

Comment: No, I included `position:relative;` for the sake of completeness, because I like to be able to see explicitly if an element is has an `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative` (etc.) position. What centres the elements is giving them an explicit `width` (eg. `.content` now has an explicit `width: 1072px;`) and specifying the left and right margins as `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.i modified both the css and html.
here is the html:

```css
<div>
    <img src="banner1.jpg" class="banner">
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="menuopmaak" >
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="tekstblok" >
  <h1>Wij zijn altijd de goedkoopste</h1>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
<div class="Loginblok" >
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input required type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="e-mail"/><br>
        <label for="password">wachtwoord</label>
            <input required type="text" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="wachtwoord"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css...

```css
ul li  {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
 
  }

.menuopmaak {
  width: 100%;
  color: #CCC;
 display:inline-block;
 width:30%;
 float:left; 
}

.tekstblok {
  background-color: #ccc;  
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display:inline-block;
  clear:both;
  width:30%; 
}
.Loginblok{
 width:30%;
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:50px;
 }
#contentmiddle {
  float:left;
}
```